# How to stop typechecking in Nextjs with TS

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have been developing a Nextjs project with TS setup. But, day by day typechecking is making much error and harder to maintain all the `@types` in my code. Can I turn off typecheking also it will not cause an error for turning of the typechecking? I mean can I make it like JS? May be I am not still fit for TS.